# SD Library writing char in a file

Tags: arduino-ide, sd-card, code-optimization, coding-standards

I'm trying to write into a file using this code from the example of the library:

```
String dataString = "";
int sensor = 0;
dataString += String(sensor);
dataString += ",";
sensor +=1;

File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
if (dataFile) {
  dataFile.println(dataString);
  dataFile.close();
}
```

I have a char array that I want to write in the file, but it works only with String objects apparently. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dataFile.write(arrayName);`

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FileWrite

Answer (score 0):

You can write char arrays? What makes you think you can't? Example:

```C++
char dataBuffer [80];
strcpy (dataBuffer, "Hello, world");

File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
if (dataFile) {
  dataFile.println(dataBuffer);
  dataFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Do C++ strings still need the '\0' char at the end?

Comment: Depends on the type of string you are talking about. The strings manipulated by the *standard library* (eg. strcpy, strcmp, strcat) expect strings to have a 0x00 byte at the end.